# Matplotlib view limit minimum is less than 1 with 2 different scales plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot different pandas columns on two different scales, I took the example from the documentation but I am unsure about the error message. Here is my piece of code:

```
# Create some mock data

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Liquidity')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price', color=color)
ax1.plot(orderbooks_hedged['topBid'], color=color)
ax1.plot(orderbooks_hedged['topAsk'], color=color)

ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx() 

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)

ax2.plot(orderbooks_hedged['topBidliquidity'], color=color)
ax2.plot(orderbooks_hedged['topAskliquidity'], color=color)

ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

And my two different dataframe columns looks like the following:

```
                      topBid    topAsk  topBidliquidity topAskliquidity
ts              
2020-06-15 09:00:07 4.145097    4.170428    24.715769   35039.309622
2020-06-15 09:00:08 4.145097    4.170428    4944.701928 35039.309622
2020-06-15 09:00:09 4.144620    4.170428    4944.701928 35039.309622
2020-06-15 09:00:10 4.144620    4.170428    4944.701928 35039.309622
```

And the error is the following:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -36879.560332175926 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value
```

I tried to google it a bit but I did not had one specific answer for my issue. Can someone help me to understand my issue? thanks!

Comment: Your `ax1.plot(orderbooks_hedged['topBid'])` only provides y-values, you also need x-values (e.g.  `ax1.plot(orderbooks_hedged.index, orderbooks_hedged['topBid'])`). Or you could try plotting via pandas which uses the index by default, e.g. `orderbooks_hedged.plot.line(y='topBid', ax=ax1)`

Comment: I tried the following ```ax1.plot(orderbooks_hedged['topAsk'], orderbooks_hedged.index, color=color) ``` but I still have that error...

Comment: Why did you reverse the order of x and y? Did you check which line gave the error? If the x axis contains pandas dates you either need pandas plotting or convert to  matplotlib dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.figure(figsize=[15,10])

color_ask = 'tab:red'
color_bid = 'tab:blue'
ax1.set_xlabel('Liquidity')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price')
ax1.plot(orderbooks_hedged.index, orderbooks_hedged['topBid'], color=color_bid)
ax1.plot(orderbooks_hedged.index, orderbooks_hedged['topAsk'], color=color_ask)

ax1.tick_params(axis='y')

ax2 = ax1.twinx() 

ax2.set_ylabel('liquidity')  # we already handled the x-label with ax1


ax2.plot(orderbooks_hedged.index, orderbooks_hedged['topBidliquidity'], color=color_bid)
ax2.plot(orderbooks_hedged.index, orderbooks_hedged['topAskliquidity'], color=color_ask)

ax2.tick_params(axis='y')

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()`enter code here`
```